# What's the best practice to store the object's current state in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I'm writing a javascript with AngularJS application that deals often with download of data from a webservice, and with that comes loading and error messages.

At first I used

```
$scope.myObj = {};
$scope.myObjReady = true|false;
$scope.myObjLoading = true|false;
$scope.myObjError = true|false;
```

So I could set the correct values for the object's state in the callbacks and the UI would automatically refresh because of angular's two way binding, but later I went for the more organized way

```
$scope.myObj = {
    data: {},
    ready: true|false,
    loading: true|false,
    error: true|false,
    errorMessage: ""
}
```

And I realised that since the object couldn't be error and loading at the same time I should move to a different approach, such as

```
$scope.myObj.state = "";
...
$scope.myObj.state = "loading"|"ready"|"error";
```

But this approach despite being faster to set the state (before this setting one to true required setting all the others to false) deals with writing a string, and I feel that's very amateur.

What would you use in this case?

Edit:
Have the AngularJS framework in mind, I can't do comparisons with objects not in scope inside the HTML UI file.

Comment: Is that a typo? `$scope.myObjReady = true|false;` -> `$scope.myObj.ready = true|false;`?

Comment: No, that's an approach having one variable for each state.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, you can have an object pretend to be an enum:

```
var STATE = {
    LOADING: 0,
    READY: 1,
    ERROR: 2
};
```

then call

```
$scope.myObj.state = STATE.LOADING;
```

The `state` variable will have 1 in it. No strings needed.

Some extended info can be found at this blog post: https://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2014/01/26/enums-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript u can make Enums like this

```
var StateEnum = Object.freeze({"LOADING":1, "READY":2, "ERROR":3});
$scope.state=StateEnum.READY;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze  to secure it

Answer (score 0):

Define enums for your cases. I.E

```
$scope.myObj.enums.LOADING_STATE_LOADING = 1
$scope.myObj.enums.LOADING_STATE_READY = 2
$scope.myObj.enums.LOADING_STATE_ERROR = 3
```

Then check for those values rather than writing in the string every time